# Finding how many people rated

Tags: average

How would I find the number of people who rated a product by knowing that everyone rated $5$ stars and when I entered a rating of $1$ the average rating went down to $4.5$.

Is there a way to find out how many people rated? I could do it manually adding $1+5+5$ and so on and divide by how many numbers are there, but is there a formula to do it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If $n$ people voted before you, what equation can you write?

Comment: It depends if the 4.5 stars is an exact average or an approximation. On many sites, you can't have 4.6 or 4.7 stars but only full stars or half stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the number of people who rated $5$ stars be $x$.

Then, we know that the total number of stars in the beginning is $5x$ and the total number of stars in the end is $4.5(x+1)$. Hence, we have the equality

$$
5x+1=4.5(x+1)=4.5x+4.5 \\
0.5x=3.5 \\
x=7
$$

Hence, the number of people who rated is $\boxed{7}$.

---

##### Generalisation

Suppose that $x$ people has rated and the average is $y$. Now, a new person votes $z$ and the average went down to $w$.

Then, we have the equality

$$
xy+z=w(x+1)=wx+w \\
x(y-w)=w-z \\
x=\frac{w-z}{y-w}
$$

Hence, the general formula for $x$ is $\boxed{\dfrac{w-z}{y-w}}$.